# Locking and reference counting with SQL ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

Tags: sql, hana, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have Java/JDBC application maintaining, among other things, two SQL database tables:

```
    MESSAGES (primary key MSG_ID) 
    RECIPIENTS (primary key USER_ID, foreign key MSG_ID)
```

Records in RECIPIENTS point to MESSAGES.MSG_ID. When a recipient dismisses the message, his (USER_ID,MSG_ID) record in RECIPIENTS should be deleted, and if he was the last remaining recipient for this MSG_ID, then the message record indicated by RECIPIENTS.MSG_ID should also be deleted from MESSAGES as well.

Simplified logic written down in pseudocode then basically would be like this:

```
    GET DB CONNECTION
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    // interlock reference counting for this MSG_ID for SELECT COUNT(*) below
    SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE MSG_ID='...' FOR UPDATE

    DELETE FROM RECIPIENTS WHERE USER_ID='...' AND MSG_ID='...'

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RECIPIENTS WHERE MSG_ID='...') == 0
    THEN DELETE FROM MESSAGES WHERE MSG_ID='...'

    COMMIT
```

Database connection pool is set in TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE mode, for the application's core logic reasons.

The question is how to avoid race condition when two users are trying to dismiss the message simultaneously.

It might be possible that users A and B start concurrent transactions, meaning (depending on exact database engine implementation) both can get an MVCC-like snapshot of database content at the start of the transaction. If so, then A will believe after DELETE FROM RECIPIENTS that it was not the last remaining recipient (seeing B as still a remaining recipient in A's snapshot); and B likewise will believe it was not the last recipient too (seeing A as still a remaining recipient in B's snapshot).

Referencing to their snapshots, both A and B will see the effect of their own DELETE FROM RECIPIENTS, but not that of a concurrent transaction. For both A and B, SELECT COUNT(*) will therefore return 1 and neither A nor B will then try to execute DELETE FROM MESSAGES.

Is there a solution to this problem that would be generic, i.e. independent of a particular DB engine, and not relying on the locking external to the database?

I would rather very much prefer (if possible) to avoid having to create a separate connection pool with a lesser transaction isolation level, just to address this issue.

Comment: Nothing happens "at the same time" when the transaction isolation level is serializable. They happen one after the other. Only one process will get the update lock on `messages`, the other will block until the other process finished its transaction. Have you experienced problems with the process you outlined?

Comment: What is your database ? Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySql, SQLServer ..... ? Each database implements isolation levels a little diferrently, there are subtle diferences in behavior, since the SQL standard in case of isolation levels is very general and does not specify details If you want help, knowing the database you're using is key here.Please edit question's tags and add a tag pointng to your database.

Comment: Currently the targeted database is SAP HANA. However I'd rather avoid engine-specific solutions as fragile. This seems to be a generic and fundamental enough problem, so I would be somewhat surprised if there is no generic solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is to establish a consistency rule based on a set of tuples (RECIPIENTS). But your application only locks one specific tuple.

No isolation level will give you a correct protocol in this case.

Alternatively, you could lock **all** tuples matching `MSG_ID` in `RECIPIENTS`, run the `DELETE` command, check how many matching tuples remain and run the second `DELETE` in case the overall remaining count is zero.

The protocol would work like this
**Tx A:**

1) lock all current records belonging to the MSG_ID
  2) DELETE the record in question
  3) Count remaining records
 4) if count = 0 delete message record
 5) COMMIT/ROLLBACK

**Tx B** (runs at any time after Tx A started):
 1) lock all current records belonging to the MSG_ID

```
 - wait until Tx A released lock via COMMIT/ROLLBACK  
 - once Tx B gets the lock, Tx A has finished all processing  
 - Tx B does not see any record from before Tx A's end
```

2) DELETE the record in question
 3) Count remaining records
 4) if count = 0 delete message record
 5) COMMIT/ROLLBACK

This schema covers all `DELETE`/`UPDATE` transactions for the RECIPIENTS table.
The only possible problem is that by only locking the records related to the message ID of interest, we don't cover the case that new recipients could be inserted just after the `count(*)` has been executed.

To avoid this situation, one would have to lock the whole table to avoid `INSERTS`. This, however, would put waiting also onto threads that don't work on the specified message ID.

Comment: Does locking by itself (SELECT FOR UPDATE) with no change to the row till COMMIT bump up a version on the locked row in the MVCC snapshot? If not, then the scheme you suggested won't work, as the conflict between the two transactions won't be recorded/detected.

Comment: Due to the explicit locking, there won't be any conflicting versions. I expanded the explanation to make it clearer. Any transaction that starts after Tx A will only ever see the state valid after Tx A finishes.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing happens "at the same time" when the transaction isolation level is serializable

I would not be so sure about it. The way it normally works, is by database engine detecting write collisions between two COMMITS, such as by comparing version numbers between the transaction's before-image and DB storage, and failing the COMMIT if the versions mismatch, leaving it up to the application to re-try the whole transaction from the very start.

However the whole point is that in this case there is no write collision. Records for RECIPIENTS.A and RECIPIENTS.B are different records and are (or can be) version-stamped independently (such as if stamping is row-based; or if it is page-based but records belong to different DB pages).

The application makes a decision (whether to delete MESSAGE) based on read-only SELECT data access incurring no write collision, and this decision is made outside of the DB engine and is unknown to the latter.